# Postman Monitor - log more information on error

Tags: postman

I have the following test in Postman

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

This runs in Postman Monitor and when the status code is not 200, the test is failing and the Monitor Console Log is displaying something like this 
    "Failed: Status code is 200
     expected response to have status code 200 but got 404".
I would like to see the actual response in the log (only if a test fails). Can this be done in a "clean" way? 
It is obviously possible to change an assertion inside pm.test to an if statement and then use console.log, but this changes the log colour to white instead of red. Besides there could be multiple test failures for the same request and I only want to log the response once. 
  So I'd like to be able to check for the number of failed tests at the end of the Tests script and if it is greater than zero log the response.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: I´m interested in the very same thing. Did you find a solution in the meantime? If so, thanks for posting it!

Comment: Interested too...